# != возвращает не все значения

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица со значениями и датой их актуализации:

```
SELECT 
    VALUE_ID,
    UF_PENETRATION_DATE,
    UF_PENETRATIONS

FROM b_uts_crm_deal
```

В таблице есть значения UF_PENETRATION_DATE в формате YYYY-MM-DD или NULL
[image: UF_PENETRATION_DATE = null]

Если условием выбрать все значения кроме текущей даты, то в ответ получим все не нулевые значения, которые соответствуют условию:

```
SELECT 
    VALUE_ID,
    UF_PENETRATION_DATE,
    UF_PENETRATIONS

FROM b_uts_crm_deal

WHERE UF_PENETRATION_DATE != '2021-01-20'
```

Чтобы получить и нулевые значение приходится использовать дополнительное условие

```
WHERE (UF_PENETRATION_DATE != "2021-01-20" 
    OR UF_PENETRATION_DATE is null)
```

Почему так?

Comment: Потому что null = null false. или по другому null ничему не равен

Comment: `NULL` - это неизвестное значение. В логике реляционных БД - одна неизвестность в общем случае не равна другой неизвестности и соотвественно `NULL` не равен самому себе, т.е. выражение `NULL = NULL` возвращает `False`. Это поведение необходимо учитывать в запросах.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1843451/5741205